# While installing cint interpreter, running ./configure returns a syntax error

Tags: c, linux, interpreter

I'm trying to install the `cint` interpreter using the instructions provided on [their website](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint) (instructions are also included below, as reference).  When running the `./configure` command, I get the following error:

```
~/cint-5.16.19$ ./configure
./configure: 23: ./configure: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

It seems odd seeing as how I didn't include any parentheses to begin with...

Any suggestions?  (Am using `bash` shell in Xubuntu 14.)

---

Instructions from `cint`:

```
$ tar xfz cint-5.16.19-source.tar.gz     <--this step worked
$ cd cint-5.16.19                        <--this step worked
$ ./configure                            <--this step not working
$ gmake
```

---

Edit: Including some more info.

The relevant line in `configure` (i.e., line 23 as referenced by the error message above) is as follows:

```
ARCHS=(linux linuxicc macgcc djgpp cygwin mingw mwerks hpux aix msvc7 msvc8 solaris solarisgcc)
```

Regarding shell compatibility, the following was included at the beginning of the `configure` file:

```
# This is a bash script, which works with any reasonable sh.
# Solaris sh is not, so we have to start bash, and call ourselves again.

[ "x$1" != "x__have_the_proper_shell@" ] && ( \
uname -a | grep -i sunos > /dev/null \
  && (bash $0 __have_the_proper_shell@ "$*") \
  || (sh $0 __have_the_proper_shell@ "$*") \
)

[ "x$1" != "x__have_the_proper_shell@" ] && exit
shift
```

Comment: Could be you are using the wrong shell. Try changing the #!shebang in the configure script. And: **what** is on line#23 of the configure script?

Comment: Lines #23 and #34 just look wrong to me, even with a shebang. Maybe you should chack another version.

Comment: @iceman Were you ever able to resolve this? I am still having this same problem on Ubuntu 14, and it is fully one year after your post.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they have fixed it in the latest version. I just tried your steps, but used the latest version from their website:

minotaur:/tmp> cd cint-5.18.00/
minotaur:/tmp/cint-5.18.00> ./configure
Guessing architecture to be linuxx8664gcc
Using current CINT core
Using /usr/lib64/libreadline.a
Using /usr/lib64/libncurses.a

Creating build dirs...
Writing Makefile.conf...
Writing cint/inc/configcint.h...
Removing Apiif.cxx
Writing bin/cint-config...
Writing config.status...
Creating Makefile...
Creating reconfigure...
Done.

Run "make" to build cint.
Run "make help" to see the available build targets.
minotaur:/tmp/cint-5.18.00>

So the configure step seems to work for cint-5.18.00 on my Slackware 13.1 system.